# how to set directory out of www or htdocs?

Tags: linux, ftp

I installed proftpd and I create the user (debian) , I set the directory to go to /var/logs , I need an ftp to enter and check the logs, the problem is when I log in it goes to /var/www and I dont know how to change it.. any idea of configuration I should do for solve this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a symlink:

```
ln -s -T /var/logs /var/www/logs
```

Also, this should probably be moved to another site.